# What is the adjective formed from 'physics'?

Tags: adjectives, derivation

As you know, the noun 'biology' forms the adjective 'biological', and 'chemistry' forms 'chemical'. What is the adjective formed from the noun 'physics'?
(It can't be physical, as this has other meanings e.g. tangible, related to real, not imaginary or metaphysical things).

Comment: It is [physical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/physical) definition 3. It's ambiguous with definition 2 as you observe, but that's what we have.

Comment: But 'physical' does not work in all circumstances. If I want to say atoms cannot be separated by chemical means, only (insert adjective from physics) means, I cannot use physical, as it has a separate meaning.

Comment: Note the name of the publication and its publisher: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=physical+review+letters

Comment: ...  not by chemical reactions, only by ***nuclear reactions***...

Comment: I think if you're worried about "physical" being vague, you could just be more specific, as @Jim alludes. In fact, you could argue that this is precisely what one does when using adjectives like "biological" or "chemical." They are all *physics*!

Comment: @user82044 Yes, that exactly what you would say, if referring to gaseous diffusion, centrifugation, etc. Atoms can be separated from other types of atoms by chemical means. I'm guessing you meant isotopes

Comment: @Jim, that's not a terribly practical way to go about it since you destroy what you are separating and it tends to be messy. And besides that, nuclear reactions *are* considered chemistry - [radiochemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiochemistry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, *physical* is the word you're looking for. I know it seems strange, because *physical* meaning "tangible" or "doctor's exam" is much more common, but look at this fourth definition from dictionary.com:

> pertaining to the physical sciences, especially physics

Or this third definition from Oxford Dictionaries:

> Relating to physics or the operation of natural forces generally

They even share the same origin (as we can see [here](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=physical)); both terms derive from the Latin word *physica*, "the study of nature". So while it may seem cumbersome, these words are just homonyms. If possible, you can also use words for subfields in physics, like *quantum*, *mechanical*, *molecular*, *nuclear*, and more.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Helpful.  But also: let's also consider the physics aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, as it pertains to the science of physics, you can use physical as the corresponding adjetive. For example, you can say that water evaporation at 100 oC is a physical process, not a chemical process. Another example: Size is a physical property of an object.